# What is a SharePoint Server Side File Hander?

Tags: security, sharepoint

In SharePoint, the definition of the 'View Only' permissions level is as follows:

> Members of this group can view pages,
>   list items, and documents. If the
>   document has a server-side file
>   handler available, they can only view
>   the document using the *server-side
>   file handler*.

What is considered to be a server-side file handler in the context of SharePoint? Is this an [HTTPHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ihttphandler.aspx)? What technology is it based on, how do I write one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The out-of-the box Server-Side file handlers are just .aspx pages.

The way file types are marked as having server-side file handler is by inclusion in the serverfilesANYTHING.xml files in SharePointRoot\TEMPLATE\XML.

Comment: So, what does this mean for the 'View Only' permission? Files with file extensions listed in these XML files cannot be downloaded and if an extension is not listed then it CAN be downloaded, correct? Is there any documentation on this topic?

Comment: Marked as 'answered' for lack of a more complete answer. Would have liked to find more documentation on the topic, but this area of SharePoint is not documented at all and for once Google provides no answers either.

Answer (score 0):

The server-side file handler displays a document in the context of the browser rather than opening the document in a client-side application (i.e. InfoPath, Excel, etc.).

Comment: I will rephrase the question as I want to know the technology it is based on